# How to transfer all non-live photos to a pc?

Tags: ios, photos, data-transfer

I have thousands of photos on my phone and want to free up storage by transferring all non-live photos to my PC through a USB. The problem is I can't find an easy way to filter out the live photos which I don't want to transfer. The only way I found is to either select all non-live photos manually or select all photos and manually deselect the non-live photos. But with thousands of photos on my phone that is unfeasible. Is there a way to do this easily?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Could you edit in the definition of what a "non Live Photo" is in your case? Is it the photos that have a very low size movie/audio clip attached to them in addition to the high quality still? Also - you might want to identify which OS and version your PC runs. Could be linux or something old or new.

Comment: Why can't you delete all live photos and move the rest? Then you could recover them? You could also just "Hide" all live photos and unhide them after the transfer.